# Get/Set AppSetting from subdirectory configuration

Tags: asp.net, web-config, subdirectory

Using ASP.NET under .NET 2.0, is it possible to get/set AppSettings in a web.config in a sub-directory, from a page in the root directory?  When I say "set", I do not need a permanent setting of the value, just simply updating the value in memory is sufficient.

I have a web application which has the standard root `web.config` file, which has system wide configuration settings.

The application also has a number of sub-directories, each one being a separate part of the system, and each having their own `web.config` file containing configurations that are only necessary for that particular section.  (All code within these sections is also built under their own individual `NameSpace`.)

Is it possible for code within the root directory to get or set an individual `<add key="" value=""/>` configuration setting from a sub-directory?

So, for example, if I call a page in the root of the web application (e.g. `~/Default.aspx`) could it somehow manually lookup an individual configuration value from the `~/Section1/web.config` file?

My guess this cannot be done, but I wanted to ask here first

---

One thought I had - that I've tried but **doesn't** work - was to have a UserControl within each section with public properties to get the values. Then dynamically load the control from with the root page code and call a property to get the value.  However, even though the UserControl is hosted with in the sub-directory, and is part of the sub-directory namespace, it is still not picking up the `web.config` settings within that sub-directory.

Comment: You can always load the config files as XML into code and read them that way.
Alternatively, why not just put the values in the subdirectory appSettings into the main-dir appSettings? They will still be accessible to the subdir code, but also to your maindir code

Comment: Sorry @Dave, had urgent support call - typical!  Yes, that is one option, but I've been an idiot and forgotten to say that what I would also like to be able to do is to temporarily SET a configuration value (i.e. just in memory, no need to update the web.config file)... I will update my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done, its one of the main limitations.

for some more information (as well as clarification on my statement) have a look [Here: Working with more than one web.config...](http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/03/23/working-with-more-then-one-web-config-files-in-asp-net-application.aspx) - the author mentions this limitation in his last paragraph before the comments.

Here is another [great resource - 10 things you should know about web.config inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx)

Comment: Thank you @Darren, this is unfortunately as I expected (but hoped would not be the case)

Comment: Yep, sucks :( you could put settings into an separate XML file or maybe a database, then they can be read/updated where-ever you fancy